# What do you call it when an ethnic slur has lost its offensive sense?

Tags: single-word-requests, linguistics

Or when the supposed target of the slur claim it as an unoffensive word and treat like something of a term of endearment among themselves.

Comment: When it’s used lovingly among the community itself, and only in that case, it’s called ***reappropriation*. Reappropriation by the community grants no license, none at all, to use such terms from outside the community. This is the more important point than the name for such terms.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **amelioration**:

> In linguistics, amelioration is the upgrading or elevation of a word's meaning, as when a word with a negative sense develops a positive one. Also called melioration or elevation.
>
> Amelioration is less common than the opposite historical process, called pejoration.
> <sub>[Amelioration (word meanings) — Glossary of Grammatical and Rhetorical Terms](https://www.thoughtco.com/amelioration-word-meanings-1689082)</sub>